# Update of options for PrimeNG Chart needs two calls instead of one

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, primeng

I use a chart of PrimeNG:

```
<p-chart type="bar" [data]="data" [options]="diagramoptions"></p-chart>
```

I've a button to change the data and options:

```
<p-button (click)="data1()" label="data1"></p-button>
```

The code to do that in the ts-file is:

```
data: any;
diagramcolors = [];
diagramoptions: any;

data1() {
   this.diagramoptions = {
      legend: {
         labels: {fontColor: 'red' },
         display: true
      }
   };

   this.data = { labels: [], datasets: [] };
   this.data.datasets.push({
      label: ['1'],
      data: ['100']          
   });
}
```

As the data is updated immediately, the options aren't - I've to call the `data1` function a second time to perform the changes.

Is there some deeper magic behind this behavior or is this a bug?

Comment: You can try to change the sort order and assign the `diagramoptions` after the `data`.

Comment: No, that doesn't help

Comment: I tried out your code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-charts-playground-qubs6w?file=app%2Fcomponents%2Fdoughnut-chart.component.ts) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Creepy - in stackblitz it works - copying the code 1:1 into my project it shows the old behavior with the double click

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it was a problem with the primeNG-Version:

After I updated from `9.0.6` to `10.0.3` the minimal example and all other worked fine.